# Can some one tell how can I register the jquery function on button click which is in master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all I am having a master page where I am having a button, where I have written some script as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnMaster").click(f2());
    });
    function f2() {
        if (isDirty == 1) {
            jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {
                if (r == true) {
                    document.location.href = "http://localhost:2758/Waitingweb/Status.aspx";

                }
                else
                    return false;

            });
            //return false;
            return false;
        }
        else {

        }
    }
</script>
```

In my master page load  I write as follows

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "PostbackClick", "$('#btnMaster').click();", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "click", "f2();", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "<script type=\"text/JavaScript\" language=\"javascript\">f2();</script>");
    }
```

But I am unable to fire the required when handling the button from content page, so can some one help me regarding this

Comment: Still the same, unable to fire the required alert

Comment: I didn't say that will solve the issue, for registering handlers you should remove the `()`.

Comment: what is the purpose of the code which you have written on **master page page load**

Comment: `krshekhar` if user click on the button which is available in master page with out saving the content of master page I am showing an alert if he confirms I will move him to the desired page if not he will stay in that page

Comment: that's ok but the purpose to write Page.ClientScript.Re......?

Comment: The script which I write is working fine when I write it in a default page with out master, but when master page exists and if I would like to achieve the same functionality it didn't work for me, so i tried to implement that way. A normal function like `function show(){ alert("Hi");}` works when I call this under page load event as follows `form1.Attributes.Add("onsubmit", "return show();");` but the script which I write is not working

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make your f2 function in a separate .js file and run that file using  tag and src="youfile.js" just like you did it and you called your jQuery file, so in this case all your pages can see the f2 function.

Answer (score 0):

on OnClientClick of button control you can call function as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="btSaveForm" runat="server" OnClientClick="f2();" />

 also check your button click jquery function:

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     $('#addButton').click(function() 
     { 
        // write your code here 
     });
 });
```